# ntlm: Missing required parameter 'digestmod'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x

Why am I getting the error `ntlm: Missing required parameter 'digestmod'` when trying to run the ansible playbook?

I researched and found that others are recommending to install `impacket` using pip which I did and yet I get the same error.

```
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.win_shell to ansible.windows.win_shell
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.win_shell to ansible.windows.win_shell
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/modules/win_shell.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.10.10.10> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5986 TO 10.10.10.10
fatal: [10.10.10.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "ntlm: Missing required parameter 'digestmod'.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

`sh-4.4# pip show impacket`

```
Name: impacket
Version: 0.10.0
Summary: Network protocols Constructors and Dissectors
Home-page: https://www.secureauth.com/labs/open-source-tools/impacket
Author: SecureAuth Corporation
Author-email: oss@secureauth.com
License: Apache modified
Location: /root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: chardet, flask, future, ldap3, ldapdomaindump, pyasn1, pycryptodomex, pyOpenSSL, six
Required-by:
```

Traceback:

```
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/hooks.py", line 30, in dispatch_hook
        _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
      File "/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_ntlm/requests_ntlm.py", line 146, in response_hook
        return self.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(
      File "/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_ntlm/requests_ntlm.py", line 117, in retry_using_http_NTLM_auth
        authenticate_message = context.create_authenticate_message(
      File "/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ntlm_auth/ntlm.py", line 104, in create_authenticate_message
        self.authenticate_message = AuthenticateMessage(user_name, password, domain_name, workstation,
      File "/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ntlm_auth/messages.py", line 245, in __init__
        self.lm_challenge_response = compute_response.get_lm_challenge_response()
      File "/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ntlm_auth/compute_response.py", line 83, in get_lm_challenge_response
        response = ComputeResponse._get_LMv2_response(self._user_name, self._password, self._domain_name,
      File "/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ntlm_auth/compute_response.py", line 208, in _get_LMv2_response
        nt_hash = comphash._ntowfv2(user_name, password, domain_name)
      File "/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ntlm_auth/compute_hash.py", line 90, in _ntowfv2
        digest = hmac.new(digest, (user_name.upper() + domain_name).encode('utf-16le')).digest()
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/hmac.py", line 190, in new
        return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/hmac.py", line 58, in __init__
        raise TypeError("Missing required parameter 'digestmod'.")
    TypeError: Missing required parameter 'digestmod'.
```

Sample playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ansible_port: 5986
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
    ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
    ansible_python_interpreter:  /usr/bin/python3.6

  tasks:
    - name: Ping Localhost
      win_shell: ping localhost
```

Comment: [_Others_](https://github.com/Porchetta-Industries/CrackMapExec/issues/386#issuecomment-637350147) has also pointed at the fact that you need an up-to-date version of `impacket`, if you just tried to install it, maybe it was, but in an outdated version. Have you tested upgrading it? Could you add, in an [edit] of your question, what does `pip show impacket` gives you?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I'm using the latest version 0.10.0.

Comment: `"/usr/local/lib/python3.8` vs `"/var/lib/testing/venv/lib/python3.6` (to say nothing of `ansible_python_interpreter:  /usr/bin/python3.6`) seems to imply your venv is running with mixed site-packages, and is almost certainly contributing to your problem

Comment: @mdaniel how can I fix this? I tried `ansible_python_interpreter` to 3.8 but still the issue exists.

Comment: Creating a fresh venv with actual isolation (so, *without* `--system-site-packages`) and using the same python your playbook is going to use. Even a "pre-playbook" play that is `- { host: localhost, tasks: [ { pip: { name: impacket } ] }` will ensure that requirement is captured in code, and not passed around the team by urban legend